# Spring boot doesn't receive request headers added from Angular client

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, http-headers, interceptor

In my demo application, I have an issue where I don't receive request headers I add from Angular client to my Spring boot server. As security measures I have SSL (Secure Socket Layer) and CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) configuration. In my application CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) is disabled. I use JWT (JSON Wen Token) as user authentication mechanism for each request. That is where my need comes to extract the JWT key from the header. I will add code samples from my application and please help me to find out the issue.

**Angular interceptor**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

/*Interceptor
  Often you’ll want to intercept HTTP requests or responses before they’re handled else where in the application*/ 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  /**
   * Constructor of InterceptorService. 
   * @param userService UserService
   */
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  /**
   * Responsible for intercepting requests. 
   * Responsible for adding 'Authorization' header with JWT (Json Web Token). 
   * @param theRequest HttpRequest<any>
   * @param handler HttpHandler
   */
  intercept(theRequest: HttpRequest<any>, handler: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    debugger;
    const jwtKey = this.userService.getJwtString();
    const authReq = theRequest.clone({
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwtKey}`
      })
    });
    console.log('Intercepted HTTP call', authReq);
    return handler.handle(authReq);
  }

}
```

**Angular user service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationConfigurationService } from './authentication-configuration.service';
import { User, AuthenticationResponse } from './data';

//Service for users 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
    //Attributes
  private jwtString: string = ''; //JWT (Jason Web Token)
  private isUserLoggedIn = false; 

  /**
   * Constructor of UserService. 
   * @param router Router
   * @param httpClient HttpClient
   */
  constructor(private router: Router, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * Executes upon user login. 
   * @param theUser User 
   */
  login(theUser: User) {
    const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
      this.httpClient.post(AuthenticationConfigurationService.getAuthenticationURL('authenticationURL') + '/getjwt', theUser, httpOptions)
                .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResponse) => {
                    this.jwtString = response.jwt;
          this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
                });
  }

  /**
   * Executes upon user logout. 
   */
  logout() {;
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false; 
    this.jwtString = '';
    this.navigateToLoginPage();
  }

  /**
   * Responsible for returning the JWT (Json Web Token) string.
   * @returns string
   */
  getJwtString(): string {
    return this.jwtString; 
  }

  /**
   * Responsible for returning whether the user is logged-in. 
   * @returns boolean
   */
  userLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.isUserLoggedIn;
  }

  /**
   * Navigate to the login page. 
   */
  private navigateToLoginPage() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }

}
```

**Spring boot security**

```
package com.example.LibraryServer.Security;

import com.example.LibraryServer.Filter.Security.JwtRequestFilter;
import com.example.LibraryServer.Services.LibraryUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Class responsible for security configurations.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //Attributes
    private final LibraryUserDetailsService libraryUserDetailsService;
    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    /**
     * Constructor of SecurityConfig.
     * @param theLibraryUserDetailsService LibraryUserDetailsService
     * @param theJwtRequestFilter JwtRequestFilter
     */
    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(LibraryUserDetailsService theLibraryUserDetailsService, JwtRequestFilter theJwtRequestFilter) {
        this.libraryUserDetailsService = theLibraryUserDetailsService;
        this.jwtRequestFilter = theJwtRequestFilter;
    }

    /**
     * Responsible for user security configuration.
     * Overridden from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter level.
     * @param theHttpSecurity HttpSecurity
     * @throws Exception - Exception upon security configuration.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity theHttpSecurity) throws Exception {
        //theHttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers("/**").access("permitAll") //Allow all paths
                /*.and().cors()*/
                //.and().csrf().disable(); //Allow all requests - CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery)
        theHttpSecurity.csrf().disable() //Allow all requests - CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery)
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate/**").access("permitAll") //Allow all paths
                .anyRequest().authenticated() //All other paths need authentication
                /*Inform spring security not to manage sessions.
                  All requests will be filtered via 'JwtRequestFilter' with JWT and does not need sessions.*/
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        //Inform spring security about the filter 'JwtRequestFilter' for username and password authentication.
        theHttpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    /**
     * Responsible for configuring user-store.
     * Overridden from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter level.
     * @param theAuthentication AuthenticationManagerBuilder
     * @throws Exception - Exception upon user store creation.
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder theAuthentication) throws Exception {
        //theAuthentication.inMemoryAuthentication()
                //.withUser("sankalpa")
                //.password("{noop}123")
                //.authorities("ROLE_USER");
        theAuthentication.userDetailsService(libraryUserDetailsService);
    }

    /**
     * Method constructing AuthenticationManager bean.
     * This method is needed since AuthenticationManager is being used in 'HelloController'.
     * Therefore this bean should be in spring application context.
     * Overridden from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter level.
     * @return AuthenticationManager
     * @throws Exception - Exception upon execution.
     */
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * Method constructing a password encoder bean.
     * Constructs 'NoOpPasswordEncoder'.
     * @return PasswordEncoder
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

**Spring boot CORS configuration class**

```
package com.example.LibraryServer.CORS;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

/**
 * Configuration class which is responsible for handling CORS.
 * Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) configuration class.
 */
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /**
     * Responsible for CORS mapping.
     * Overridden from WebMvcConfigurer level.
     * @param theRegistry CorsRegistry
     */
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(@NotNull CorsRegistry theRegistry) {
        //End points
        var authorizedEndpoints = new String[] {
                "/book/**",
                "/author/**",
                "/authenticate/**"
        };

        //Add mapping
        for (var endPoint : authorizedEndpoints) {
            theRegistry.addMapping(endPoint)
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                    .allowedMethods("*") //"HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH"
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowCredentials(true)
                    .exposedHeaders("Authorization");
        }
    }

}
```

**Spring boot filter**

```
package com.example.LibraryServer.Filter.Security;

import com.example.LibraryServer.Services.LibraryUserDetailsService;
import com.example.LibraryServer.Uilities.JsonWebTokenUtility;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Filter class for intercepting all the requests and validate with JWT (Jason Web Token).
 */
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    //Attributes
    private final LibraryUserDetailsService libraryUserDetailsService;
    private final JsonWebTokenUtility jsonWebTokenUtility;

    /**
     * Constructor of JwtRequestFilter.
     * @param theLibraryUserDetailsService LibraryUserDetailsService
     * @param theJsonWebTokenUtility JsonWebTokenUtility
     */
    @Autowired
    public JwtRequestFilter(LibraryUserDetailsService theLibraryUserDetailsService, JsonWebTokenUtility theJsonWebTokenUtility) {
        this.libraryUserDetailsService = theLibraryUserDetailsService;
        this.jsonWebTokenUtility = theJsonWebTokenUtility;
    }

    /**
     * Responsible for intercepting the request via filter and do the validations and needful with JWT.
     * Overridden from OncePerRequestFilter level.
     * @param theRequest HttpServletRequest
     * @param theResponse HttpServletResponse
     * @param theChain FilterChain
     * @throws ServletException - Exception upon execution.
     * @throws IOException - Exception upon execution.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest theRequest, HttpServletResponse theResponse, FilterChain theChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        printLog("doFilterInternal() -> Executed");
        //Get the 'Authorization' from the request header. JWT is suppose to send in request header under 'Authorization'.
        final String authorizationHeader = theRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

        //Method local attributes
        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        //Get the JWT String and username out from 'authorizationHeader'
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            printLog("doFilterInternal() -> Extracting the JWT token from the authorization header");
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jsonWebTokenUtility.extractUserName(jwt);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            printLog("doFilterInternal() -> User name found: " + username + " and there is no current logged-in user");
            //If the username is not null and there is no current user authenticated

            //Get the user from user details service
            UserDetails userDetails = this.libraryUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jsonWebTokenUtility.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                printLog("doFilterInternal() -> Load user for the username: " + userDetails.getUsername() +
                        " and validated the JWT successfully");
                //Validating user with the JWT String is successful

                //Create token
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                printLog("doFilterInternal() -> Created 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken'");
                //Set the information to the token
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(theRequest));
                printLog("doFilterInternal() -> Set details to the 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken'");
                //Set the authorized user to the context
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                printLog("doFilterInternal() -> Set 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken' to the 'SecurityContextHolder'");
            }
        }
        //Continue the chain
        printLog("doFilterInternal() -> Continue the chain...");
        theChain.doFilter(theRequest, theResponse);
    }

    /**
     * Responsible for printing main log messages to the console.
     * @param theLogMessage String
     */
    private void printLog(String theLogMessage) {
        log.info("JwtRequestFilter: " + theLogMessage);
    }

}
```

In the above filter I am suppose to get the 'Authorization' out of the header but there is no header at all for the requests. When I do the same via Postman it works perfectly. This happens when I do this via Angular client.

**Debug**
[image]

Comment: Can you show this.userService?

Comment: When it works with postman then your angular request may be corrupt. Did you inspected the request on client side and it has a valid header object?

Comment: @MikeOne I did edit the question body and added user service class as well.

Comment: @DaniR I did put the debugger; to the interceptor intercept() and checked whether the header is added and that code executes. Is there any other way to make sure the header is added for sure? thank you

Comment: Try: `headers: theRequest.headers.set('Authorization': 'Bearer token')`. I think you don't want to override the origin request headers. But i am not that familiar with angular interceptors. You also can add `console.log(theRequest)` and inspect the headers object.

Comment: @DaniR Can you check my main question again, I did add a new image there. I have a little doubt. All headers are added under lazy update array. Does that make a difference ?

Comment: Seems correct. Is your server running with https? Have you done your postman request with https or http?

Comment: @DaniR Yes, I am running my server with https. I've created my own PKCS12 via keytool and added it to the keystore. I did send Postman requests with https as well and it works. Even now I receive my requests in the server from Angular client but when I filter the requests, the headers are missing. That's why I cannot proceed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same issue. in my case i was getting a cors error in the preflight call.
adding http.cors() as below solved my issue.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.headers().cacheControl();

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .....;
        http.cors();
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Adding the http.cors() to the HttpSecurity in the configure() method solved the issue. Now it is working and thanks!

Comment: The best answer! `http.cors()` Thanks!!

Comment: Best Answer ever